# Set the context of an activity to secondary display?

Tags: android, android-activity

For a project I would like to create an activity on a secondary display. I do not want to use the Presentation class, as this creates dialogs instead of activities. I am able to retrieve the secondary display and it's context however am unable to target this context for a new activity. Here is my current code:

```
MediaRouter.RouteInfo selectedRoute = mMediaRouter.getSelectedRoute(
            MediaRouter.ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO);
Display selectedDisplay = null;
Intent intent = null;
if (selectedRoute != null) {
    selectedDisplay = selectedRoute.getPresentationDisplay();
}
if(selectedDisplay != null){
    Context myC = createDisplayContext(selectedDisplay);

    //indicates that the display represented by myC is not the main display
    System.out.println(((WindowManager) myC.getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).
            getDefaultDisplay());

    intent = new Intent(myC, MainActivity.class);
    //required flag to use myC.startActivity(), instead of just startActivity()
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    myC.startActivity(intent);
}
```

This code executes without error however, the activity that is created appears on top of the first activity on the main screen. Printing the default display of the created activity confirms this.

Is it possible to create an activity on a secondary screen? The fact that the Presentation class is a subclass of Dialog would suggest that it may not be.